# Sum NSString values of Struct

Tags: swift

I've defined a Struct like this

```
struct CartItem {
    var name: String
    var quantity: NSString
    var price: NSString
}
```

Now, i want to calculate a total of cart and write it in a label, `quantity * price`.
But, i have to use NSString because there are quotes in my numeric values.

In my tableviewcell i can show the value with "as String". But if i have to calculate a simple sum of price like this:

```
let sum = CartItems.lazy.map { $0.price }.reduce(0, +)
```

it returns an error: Cannot convert value of type 'NSString' to closure result type 'Int'.

Someone can help me with this?

Comment: You need to extract the real numeric value from your `price` Strings. Can you show an example of how these look?

Comment: @Gereon print of the array : [Vice.CartItem(name: "seconda", quantity: 1, price: 6), Vice.CartItem(name: "seconda", quantity: 3, price: 6), Vice.CartItem(name: "seconda", quantity: 1, price: 6), Vice.CartItem(name: "quinta", quantity: 4, price: 8)]

Comment: But all your price and quantity values are plain numbers in that example so what do you mean with "quotes in numeric values"? And please add examples like this to your question rather than posting them as comments. And of course, you shouldn't use NSString but String instead.

Comment: Stefano - all of these examples could have price as a number - can you show a 'problem' example?

Comment: I'm using Firebase. In my app, when user order a product, Firebase creates a child with price like "6", and quantity like "2". With casting as NSString into Cart tableView, i can eliminate this quotes. This is the problem, it seems a real numeric value, but it's a NSString.

Comment: My question is, how can i transform the price and quantity properties in Int values?

Comment: While you *can* solve this problem by parsing strings into numbers as you sum them, but I wouldn't recommend that. You should use appropriate data types for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `floatValue` on `NSString` and calculate the sum as,

```
let sum = CartItems.lazy.map { $0.price.floatValue * $0.quantity.floatValue }.reduce(0, +)
```

Or using `intValue`,

```
let sum = CartItems.lazy.map { $0.price.intValue * $0.quantity.intValue }.reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: @StefanoQuarta Are you sure the `price` and `quantity` has a non-zero value?

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `NSString` in Swift at all (except maybe in a few obscure CoreFoundation APIs)

```
struct CartItem {
    var name: String
    var quantity: String
    var price: String
}
```

Secondly if the values are guaranteed to be numeric just convert them. As a price is involved `Double` might be more reasonable than `Int`.

And please name variables with starting lowercase letter.

```
let sum = cartItems.lazy.map{ Double($0.price)! * Double($0.quantity)! }.reduce(0.0, +)
```

If the values could contain letters and other characters use the *nil coalescing operator* to assign a default value if the string cannot be converted

```
 let sum = cartItems.lazy.map{ (Double($0.price) ?? 0.0) * Double($0.quantity) && 0.0 }.reduce(0.0, +)
```

To get rid of all this conversion stuff declare price and quantity in the database as numeric types

Comment: I'm using NSString because i'm casting values from Firebase like "6". With NSString i can delete quotes

Comment: This is irrelevant. `String` and `NSString` behave basically the same. And `NSString` does not *delete quotes*, nor does `String`.

Comment: @StefanoQuarta Why would you use String for price and quantity? You should use Int and Decimal or Double and convert from string to value when fetching that from Firebase